# Extraxting multiple types of variables from one long string

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have imported a CSV file into R. It generates 8 columns. it has like 200 rows (or observations) All my relevant data is in row 5 in one single character "variable". Here is an example of one observation from row 5:

```
{"answers":{"#userdefined-7fb430bc-3615-0373-89c6-e155172da89c":6,"attachedVsSorrowful":1,"dysregulation":0,"note":"I had a lovely day","skills":[0,1,3,4,5,6,9,10,11,12,14,15,18,19,21]},"date":1.4878944e+12...
```

I'd love to create a data frame with i.e the labels:

```
c("attachedVsSorrowful","dysregulation"......)
```

- I need to extract: ordinal ,a matrix,a string and a date format variable

so 2 questions:

1. What packages and R-commands do I use?
2. Can you point me to relevant ressources where I can learn to do this?

Would Tidyr/dplyr be a viable option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your variable is Json formatted. Json comes from the javascript world: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

But there are r packages to read Json: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/vignettes/json-aaquickstart.html

```
js <- jsonlite::fromJSON('{"answers":{"#userdefined-7fb430bc-3615-0373-89c6-e155172da89c":6,"attachedVsSorrowful":1,"dysregulation":0,"note":"I had a lovely day","skills":[0,1,3,4,5,6,9,10,11,12,14,15,18,19,21]},"date":1.4878944e+12}'
                         , simplifyVector = FALSE)

str(js)
 'data.frame':  1 obs. of  20 variables:
 $ answers..userdefined.7fb430bc.3615.0373.89c6.e155172da89c: int 6
 $ answers.attachedVsSorrowful                              : int 1
 $ answers.dysregulation                                    : int 0
 $ answers.note                                             : chr "I had a lovely day"
 $ answers.skills.0L                                        : int 0
 $ answers.skills.1L                                        : int 1
 $ answers.skills.3L                                        : int 3
 $ answers.skills.4L                                        : int 4
 $ answers.skills.5L                                        : int 5
 $ answers.skills.6L                                        : int 6
 $ answers.skills.9L                                        : int 9
 $ answers.skills.10L                                       : int 10
 $ answers.skills.11L                                       : int 11
 $ answers.skills.12L                                       : int 12
 $ answers.skills.14L                                       : int 14
 $ answers.skills.15L                                       : int 15
 $ answers.skills.18L                                       : int 18
 $ answers.skills.19L                                       : int 19
 $ answers.skills.21L                                       : int 21
 $ date                                                     : num 1.49e+12
```

Comment: one further clarification needed: I have a CSV file with 8 rows. So It's only one of the rows that contains this son-format, the rest will probably be easy to add once I have the data frame ready. Could anyone point me in direction of how to get all the observations in the same data frame. The proposed solution is for taking out one observation. Also when I use the jasonlite solution it multiplies the observations, since one of the variables, "skills" is a vector, and the number multiplied is number of number off variables in the vector. How to avoid this?

Comment: use the simplifyVector = FALSE flag. I've edited the answer ;)

Comment: Got it - great ! that works, fantastic, Thx Fabian :0) However, I start out from a CSV file with 200 observations of this kind, and I even have multiple subjects answering. So this observation with 20 entries needs to be multiplied by 250 days and 80 subjects answering. Could you point towards a code or viable strategy to get all this into the data frame

Comment: running in to trouble here: Error in source("~/.active-rstudio-document", echo = TRUE) : 
  string at line 70 containing Unicode escapes not in this locale
is too long (max 10000 chars)